# Error al crear Scroll infinito

Tags: php, ajax, scroll

Estoy tratando de crear un `Scroll` infinito, pero al momento de correrlo me aparece un error de referencia en el `GET`

> jquery.js:8706 GET http://localhost/loadMoreData.php?last_id=9 404 (Not Found)

el codigo de mi `Script` es:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function() { <-- linea donde me marca error
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
            var last_id = $(".post-id:last").attr("id");
            loadMoreData(last_id);
        }
    });

    function loadMoreData(last_id){
      $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/loadMoreData.php?last_id=' + last_id,
                type: "get",
                beforeSend: function()
                {
                    $('.ajax-load').show();
                }
            })
            .done(function(data)
            {
                $('.ajax-load').hide();
                $("#post-data").append(data);
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {
                  alert('server not responding...');
            });
    }
</script>
```

Este es el codigo que tengo en `loadMoreData:`

```
$conexion = conexion($bd_config);

$qry = "SELECT * FROM publications WHERE id < $_GET['last_id'] ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 8"; 
$result = $conexion->query($qry);

$json = include('views/empleos.php');

echo json_encode($json);
```

y este es mi codigo donde se muestran los `post`:

```
<?php while ($post = $result -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>

    <div class="box-list" id="post-data">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
              <p class="post-id" id="<?php echo $post['id']; ?>">
                <div class="col-md-1 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    <div class="img-item"><img src="<?php echo OTRA; ?>/images/<?php echo $post['thumb']; ?>" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <h3 class="no-margin-top"><a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>"><?php echo $post['titulo']; ?> <i class="fa fa-link color-white-mute font-1x"></i></a></h3>
                    <h5><span class="color-black"><?php echo $post['company']; ?></span> - <span class="color-white-mute"><?php echo $post['locacion']; ?></span></h5>
                    <p class="text-truncate "><?php echo $post['extracto']; ?></p>
                    <div>
                    <span class="color-white-mute"><?php echo fecha($post['fecha']); ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

pero si esta trayendo todo de la base de datos, no se que pasa, apenas comence a usar ajax

Comment: Parece que antes de tu script no estás cargando jquery. Puedes verificarlo?

Comment: De hecho me parecio que fue por la version, estaba usando la 3.2.1 y la cambie por la 1.9.1 y "funciono" lo digo asi por que al momento de entrar a la variable de `last_id` no la reconoce y me tira el `.fail`

Comment: @AngelCid estoy usando este blog como ejemplo [http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-infinite-scroll-pagination-using-jquery-ajax-exampleexample.html]